# How to set json file to object's array in Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

how to set json file to my "Client" object's array?
I have json, which looks like this:
Clients.json

```
{
   "clients": [
   {
      "firstName": "nameA",
      "lastName": "lastA",
      "doctorsName": "domm",
      "procedure": "consultation",
      "registrationDate": "new Date(2019, 10, 12)",
      "isAlreadyServed": "false"
   },
   {
      "firstName": "nameB",
      "lastName": "lastB",
      "doctorsName": "domm",
      "procedure": "procedureA",
      "registrationDate": "new Date(2019, 10, 12)",
      "isAlreadyServed": "false"
   },
   {
      "firstName": "nameC",
      "lastName": "lastC",
      "doctorsName": "doctorA",
      "procedure": "procedureC",
      "registrationDate": "new Date(2019, 10, 12)",
      "isAlreadyServed": "false"
   },

   ...
   ...
   ...
```

And how can I set it to object's array Client.service.ts

```
clients: Client[] = this.http.get('path.Clients.json') // ??
```

Comment: As explained in the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your data is in the client-side as a JSON file. Though you can use `HttpClient`, here is another solution for the same.

You can directly import the JSON as a constant and assign it to `clients` as of TS 2.9 ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#new---resolvejsonmodule)).

```js
import Clients from 'path/to/client/json';

clients: ClientsJson = Clients;
```

where the `ClientsJson` interface would look like this.

```js
export interface ClientsJson {
    clients: Client[];
}

export interface Client {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    doctorsName: string;
    procedure: string;
    registrationDate: Date;
    isAlreadyServed: boolean;
}
```

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-import-client-json).

Answer (score 1):

You first need to define an interface that matches your object structure:

```
public interface ClientConfiguration {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    doctorsName: string;
    // And so on...
}
```

Then, just like the code you have shown, you need to *type* the `http.get` method in order to obtain the correct output.

```
public getConfiguration(): Observable<Array<ClientConfiguration>> {
    return this.http.get<Array<ClientConfiguration>>('path/to/client/json');
}
```

Since my `getConfiguration()` method returns an observable, you will need to subscribe to it in your components or services:

```
@Component({ ... })
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getConfiguration().subscribe(result: Array<ClientConfiguration> => {
             this.clientConfiguration = result;
        });
    }

    public getConfiguration(): Observable<Array<ClientConfiguration>> {
        return this.http.get<Array<ClientConfiguration>>('path/to/client/json');
    }
}
```

You can read more here about `HttpClient` at Angular's official documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http

Hope it helps.